# Stagnant validation accuracy during training of vgg net with 10000 images

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

I have 10000 images 5000 diseased Medical images and 5000 healthy images,
I used vgg16 and modified last layers as follows

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, 224, 224, 3)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 224, 224, 64)      1792      
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 224, 224, 64)      36928     
_________________________________________________________________
block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 112, 112, 64)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 112, 112, 128)     73856     
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 112, 112, 128)     147584    
_________________________________________________________________
block2_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 56, 56, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 56, 56, 256)       295168    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 56, 56, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 56, 56, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 28, 28, 256)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 28, 28, 512)       1180160   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 28, 28, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 28, 28, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 14, 14, 512)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 7, 7, 512)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 25088)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
fc1 (Dense)                  (None, 256)               6422784   
_________________________________________________________________
fc2 (Dense)                  (None, 128)               32896     
_________________________________________________________________
output (Dense)               (None, 2)                 258       
=================================================================
Total params: 21,170,626
Trainable params: 6,455,938
Non-trainable params: 14,714,688
```

My code is as follows

```
import numpy as np
import os
import time
from vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.preprocessing import image
from imagenet_utils import preprocess_input, decode_predictions
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers import merge, Input
from keras.models import Model
from keras.utils import np_utils
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

# Loading the training data
PATH = '/mount'
# Define data path
data_path = PATH 
data_dir_list = os.listdir(data_path)

img_data_list=[]
y=0;
for dataset in data_dir_list:
    img_list=os.listdir(data_path+'/'+ dataset)
    print ('Loaded the images of dataset-'+'{}\n'.format(dataset))
    for img in img_list:
        img_path = data_path + '/'+ dataset + '/'+ img 
        img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
        x = image.img_to_array(img)
        x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
        x = preprocess_input(x)
        x = x/255

        y=y+1
        print('Input image shape:', x.shape)
        print(y)
        img_data_list.append(x)
from keras.optimizers import SGD
sgd = SGD(lr=1e-3, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)

img_data = np.array(img_data_list)
#img_data = img_data.astype('float32')
print (img_data.shape)
img_data=np.rollaxis(img_data,1,0)
print (img_data.shape)
img_data=img_data[0]
print (img_data.shape)

# Define the number of classes
num_classes = 2
num_of_samples = img_data.shape[0]
labels = np.ones((num_of_samples,),dtype='int64')

labels[0:5001]=0
labels[5001:]=1

names = ['YES','NO']

# convert class labels to on-hot encoding
Y = np_utils.to_categorical(labels, num_classes)

#Shuffle the dataset
x,y = shuffle(img_data,Y, random_state=2)
# Split the dataset
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=2)

image_input = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))

model = VGG16(input_tensor=image_input, include_top=True,weights='imagenet')

model.summary()

last_layer = model.get_layer('block5_pool').output
x= Flatten(name='flatten')(last_layer)
x = Dense(256, activation='relu', name='fc1')(x)
x = Dense(128, activation='relu', name='fc2')(x)
out = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax', name='output')(x)
custom_vgg_model2 = Model(image_input, out)
custom_vgg_model2.summary()

# freeze all the layers except the dense layers
for layer in custom_vgg_model2.layers[:-3]:
    layer.trainable = False

custom_vgg_model2.summary()

custom_vgg_model2.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer=sgd,metrics=['accuracy'])

t=time.time()
#   t = now()
hist = custom_vgg_model2.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=50, verbose=1, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
print('Training time: %s' % (t - time.time()))
(loss, accuracy) = custom_vgg_model2.evaluate(X_test, y_test, batch_size=10, verbose=1)

print("[INFO] loss={:.4f}, accuracy: {:.4f}%".format(loss,accuracy * 100))
model.save("vgg_10000.h5")
```

The result i'm posting first 5 and last 5 epochs

```
Epoch 1/50
8000/8000 [==============================] - 154s - loss: 0.6960 - acc: 0.5354 - val_loss: 0.6777 - val_acc: 0.5745
Epoch 2/50
8000/8000 [==============================] - 134s - loss: 0.6684 - acc: 0.5899 - val_loss: 0.6866 - val_acc: 0.5490
Epoch 3/50
8000/8000 [==============================] - 134s - loss: 0.6608 - acc: 0.6040 - val_loss: 0.6625 - val_acc: 0.5925
Epoch 4/50
8000/8000 [==============================] - 134s - loss: 0.6518 - acc: 0.6115 - val_loss: 0.6668 - val_acc: 0.5810
Epoch 5/50
8000/8000 [==============================] - 134s - loss: 0.6440 - acc: 0.6280 - val_loss: 0.6990 - val_acc: 0.5580
```

last 5

```
Epoch 25/50
8000/8000 [==============================] - 134s - loss: 0.5944 - acc: 0.6720 - val_loss: 0.6271 - val_acc: 0.6485
Epoch 26/50
8000/8000 [==============================] - 134s - loss: 0.5989 - acc: 0.6699 - val_loss: 0.6483 - val_acc: 0.6135
Epoch 27/50
8000/8000 [==============================] - 134s - loss: 0.5950 - acc: 0.6789 - val_loss: 0.7130 - val_acc: 0.5785
Epoch 28/50
8000/8000 [==============================] - 134s - loss: 0.5853 - acc: 0.6838 - val_loss: 0.6263 - val_acc: 0.6395
```

The results are not that great I tweked around using 128 and 128 nodes in last two layers using adam optimizer etc still results are not that convincing. Any help is much appriciated.

Comment: @ldavid can u check this up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

- Perform a stratified [train_test_split](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html)

  ```
  train_test_split(x, y, stratify=y, test_size=0.2, random_state=2)
  ```
- Look into your data, and see if there are outliers in the images.
- Use adam optimizer: `from keras.optimizers import Adam` instead of `SGD`
- Try other seeds wherever applicable, i.e instead of `random_state=2`, use something else:

  ```
  X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
                                 x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=382938)
  ```
- Try with `include_top=False`:

  ```
  model = VGG16(input_tensor=image_input, include_top=False,weights='imagenet')
  ```
- Use `(train, validation, test)` sets or `(cross-validation, holdout)` sets to get a more reliable performance metric.

Comment: is there anything wrong with the dense layer configuration is the number of parameters too low or high?. Also fine-tuning of the dense layer or should I try to fine-tune the last convolution layer also? @MedAli

Comment: @sachsom yes you should definitely play with the number of layers to freeze. As the convolution layers will create the filters that are going to help make the distinction between the two classes of your problem. If you freeze all of them, it's as if you are assuming that the same Imagenet convolutional filters are applicable to your problem.